# Eclipse project won't run on android 5.0 emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I downloaded the 5.0 SDK from the Android SDK Manager. I created two varations of emulators after the first one didn't show up in "Choose a running Android device"

- 3.7" API 21 ARMv7a 512 ram 32 heap 200mb storage + snapshot
- 4.0" API 21 ARMv7a 1024 ram 32 heap 200mb storage + snapshot

these emulators work fine pre 5.0 but now they aren't working. Has anyone found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to choose a skin to see if it works for you?

Comment: The Virtual Device Manager makes you select a skin before you can save a device in the first place.